# I am getting this error in my code: Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift

I am building a Quiz app and I am getting this error: Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range. This is the piece of code that is getting flagged: choice2.setTitle(answerChoices[1], for: .normal). In the file where there are questions, after line 40 the code crashes all the time.

This is the ViewController:

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Quizzler-iOS13
//  Created by 3N0Z on 22/09/2023.

import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var finishedQuiz: UIButton!
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLalbel: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var choice1: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var choice2: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var choice3: UIButton!
    
    var quizBrain = QuizBrain()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            
        
        updateUI()
        
    }
    func endQuiz () {

        if quizBrain.questionNumber == 10 {
    
    finishedQuiz.alpha = 1

        choice1.alpha = 0
        choice2.alpha = 0
        choice3.alpha = 0
    }


    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        
        let userGotItRight = quizBrain.checkAnswer(userAnswer: userAnswer)
        
        if userGotItRight {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        
        quizBrain.nextQuestion()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    func start(){
        
        finishedQuiz.alpha = 0
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
        questionLabel.text = quizBrain.getQuestionText()
        
        //Need to fetch the answers and update the button titles using the setTitle method.
        let answerChoices = quizBrain.getAnswers()
        choice1.setTitle(answerChoices[0], for: .normal)
        choice2.setTitle(answerChoices[1], for: .normal)
        choice3.setTitle(answerChoices[2], for: .normal)
        
        
        choice1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        choice2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        choice3.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        
        progressBar.progress = quizBrain.getProgress()
        scoreLalbel.text = "Score: \(quizBrain.getScore())"
        
    }
    
}
```

Here is the Question struct:

```
//  Question.swift
//  Quizzler-iOS13
//
//  Created by 3N0Z on 2023-09-12.


import Foundation

struct Question {
    
    let text: String
    //Multiple choice questions have multiple answers, an Array of Strings would work for our quiz data.
    let answers : [String] // <- Here
    //Look at the data in the quiz array, there is a seperate string that is the correctAnswer.
    let correctAnswer: String
    //The initialiser needs to be updated to match the new multiple choice quiz data.
    init(q: String, a: [String], rightAnswer: String) { // <- Here
        text = q
        answers = a
        correctAnswer = rightAnswer
        
    }
}
```

And these are the the questions the filename is QuizBrain:

```
//  QuizBrain.swift
//  Quizzler-iOS13
//
//  Created by 3N0Z on 2023-09-29.


import Foundation

struct QuizBrain {
    
    public var questionNumber = 0
    
    var score = 0
    
    let quiz = [
        Question(q: "Which is the largest organ in the human body?", a: ["Heart", "Skin", "Large Intestine"], rightAnswer: "Skin"),
            Question(q: "Five dollars is worth how many nickels?", a: ["25", "50", "100"], rightAnswer: "100"),
            Question(q: "What do the letters in the GMT time zone stand for?", a: ["Global Meridian Time", "Greenwich Mean Time", "General Median Time"], rightAnswer: "Greenwich Mean Time"),
        Question(q: "What is the French word for 'hat'?", a: ["Chapeau", "Écharpe", "Bonnet"], rightAnswer: "Chapeau"),
            Question(q: "In past times, what would a gentleman keep in his fob pocket?", a: ["Notebook", "Handkerchief", "Watch"], rightAnswer: "Watch"),
        Question(q: "How would one say goodbye in Spanish?", a: ["Au Revoir", "Adiós", "Salir"], rightAnswer: "Adiós"),
        Question(q: "Which of these colours is NOT featured in the logo for Google?", a: ["Green", "Orange", "Blue"], rightAnswer: "Orange"),
        Question(q: "What alcoholic drink is made from molasses?", a: ["Rum", "Whisky", "Gin"], rightAnswer: "Rum"),
        Question(q: "What type of animal was Harambe?", a: ["Panda", "Gorilla", "Crocodile"], rightAnswer: "Gorilla"),
        Question(q: "Where is Tasmania located?", a: ["Indonesia", "Australia", "Scotland"], rightAnswer: "Australia"),
        Question(q: "Which city is home to the Brandenburg Gate?", a: ["Vienna", "Zurich", "Berlin"], rightAnswer:"Berlin"),
        Question(q: "Where was the first example of paper money used?", a: ["China","Turkek","Greece"], rightAnswer:"China"),
        Question(q: "Who is generally considered the inventor of the motor car?", a: ["Henry Ford", "Karl Benz", "Henry M. Leland"], rightAnswer:"Karl Benz"),
        Question(q: "What number was the Apollo mission that successfully put a man on the moon for the first time in human history? ", a: ["Apollo 11", "Apollo 12", "Apollo 13"], rightAnswer:"Apollo 11"),
        Question(q: "Which of the following languages has the longest alphabet?", a: ["Greek", "Russian", "Arabic"], rightAnswer:"Russian"),
        Question(q: "Who was the lead singer of the band The Who?", a: ["Roger Daltrey", "Don Henley", "Robert Plant"], rightAnswer:"Roger Daltrey"),
        Question(q: "What spirit is used in making a Tom Collins?", a: ["Vodka", "Rum", "Gin"], rightAnswer:"Gin"),
        Question(q: "The fear of insects is known as what?", a: ["Entomophobia", "Arachnophobia", "Ailurophobia"], rightAnswer:"Entomophobia"),
        Question(q: " What was the name of the Franco-British supersonic commercial plane that operated from 1976-2003?", a: ["Accord", "Concorde", "Mirage"], rightAnswer:"Concorde"),
        Question(q: "Which horoscope sign is a fish?", a: ["Aquarius", "Cancer", "Pisces"], rightAnswer:"Pisces"),
        Question(q: "What is the name for the Jewish New Year?", a: ["Hanukkah", "Rosh Hashanah", "Kwanza"], rightAnswer:"Rosh Hashanah"),
        Question(q: "What is the longest word in the English language?", a: ["Antidisestablishmentarianism", "Hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia", "Floccinaucinihilipilification"], rightAnswer:"Antidisestablishmentarianism"),
        Question(q: "What is the name of the world’s smallest horse?", a: ["Falabella", "Shetland pony", "Miniature horse"], rightAnswer:"Miniature horse"),
        Question(q: "What is Benedictine monk Dom Pierre Pérignon rumored to have created?", a: ["Tomato ketchup", "Champagne", "French fries"], rightAnswer:"Champagne"),
        Question(q: "Which country drinks the most amount of coffee per person? ", a: ["Finland, Italy, Colombia "], rightAnswer:"Finland"),
        Question(q: "What is the collective name for a group of unicorns?", a: ["A sparkle", "A spell", "A blessing"], rightAnswer:"A blessing"),
        Question(q: "What is the most common color of toilet paper in France?", a: ["Pink", "White", "Blue"], rightAnswer:"Pink"),
        Question(q: "How many years old is the world’s oldest piece of chewing gum? ", a: ["100", "2,500", "5,700"], rightAnswer:"5,700"),
        Question(q: "How many times per day does the average American open their fridge?", a: ["5", "33", "22"], rightAnswer:"33"),
        Question(q: "What color is an airplane’s famous black box?", a: ["Red", "Orange", "Black"], rightAnswer:"Orange"),
        Question(q: "On a boat, what is the opposite of port?", a: ["Bow", "Starboard", "Deck"], rightAnswer:"Starboard"),
        Question(q: "In what language is the phrase ‘Hakuna Matata’?", a: ["Dutch", "Swahili", "Yoruba"], rightAnswer:"Swahili"),
        Question(q: "Did you enjoy this quiz?", a: ["Yes & continue", "No & continue", "Continue"], rightAnswer:"You will never get his one"),
    ]
    
    
    func getQuestionText() -> String {
        return quiz[questionNumber].text
    }
    
    //Need a way of fetching the answer choices.
    func getAnswers() -> [String] {
        return quiz[questionNumber].answers
    }
    
    func getProgress() -> Float {
        return Float(questionNumber) / Float(quiz.count)
    }
    
    mutating func getScore() -> Int {
        return score
    }
    
     mutating func nextQuestion() {
        
        if questionNumber + 1 < quiz.count {
            questionNumber += 1
        } else {
            questionNumber = 0
        }
    }
    
    
    
    mutating func checkAnswer(userAnswer: String) -> Bool {
        //Need to change answer to rightAnswer here.
        if userAnswer == quiz[questionNumber].correctAnswer {
            score += 1
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to check the code for errors and looked on StackOverflow, Reddit, and online for solutions but nothing worked. Send help.

Comment: Try to validate `answerChoices` before getting its indices. You will find the incorrect data format. At first glance, I see it's fine, maybe you're accidentally editing the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read your code carefully. It's just a typo.

Replace

```
Question(q: "Which country drinks the most amount of coffee per person? ", 
         a: ["Finland, Italy, Colombia "], rightAnswer:"Finland"),
```

with

```
Question(q: "Which country drinks the most amount of coffee per person? ", 
         a: ["Finland", "Italy", "Colombia"], rightAnswer:"Finland"),
```

And what country is `Turkek`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple robust fix to avoid `Fatal error: Index out of range`, is to check the index first before accessing an array element.

In your `QuizBrain` (and elsewhere), I suggest that whenever
you access the `quiz` array, you check
the index, such as:

```
   if questionNumber < quiz.count { .... quiz[questionNumber] }
```

Similarly when using `answerChoices`, check the index first.

```
     if 2 < answerChoices.count {
         choice1.setTitle(answerChoices[0], for: .normal)
         choice2.setTitle(answerChoices[1], for: .normal)
         choice3.setTitle(answerChoices[2], for: .normal)
     }
```

This way you will not get the Fatal error: Index out of range.

Comment: As the questions are hard-coded the developer should take the responsibility and write a test at *develop time*.